# Load apache camel routes at runtime and add to existing CamelContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying  to load an Apache Camel routes at runtime and add to existing CamelContext. I have route defined like below ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <routeContext id="message" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="abcRoute" autoStartup="false">
            <from uri="activemq:input"/>
            <delay>
                <constant>1000</constant>
            </delay>
            <to uri="activemq:output"/>
        </route>
    </routeContext>

</beans>
```

I see , it was passible to load camel routes at runtime using loadRoutesDefinition in camel2 as below ,

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("MyRoute.xml");
    RoutesDefinition routesDefinition = camelContext.loadRoutesDefinition(is);
camelContext.addRouteDefinitions(routesDefinition.getRoutes());
```

I am looking for possible way to load camel routes in camel3 at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load route definitions from files by using *ExtendedCamelContext*, adapting your Camel context:

```
    ExtendedCamelContext ecc = camelContext.adapt(ExtendedCamelContext.class);
    Resource resource = ResourceHelper.fromBytes("resource.xml", bytes);
    ecc.getRoutesLoader().loadRoutes(resource);
```

where *bytes* is the byte array that stores the content of your file.

Comment: Thanks for reply . but i want to add or delete routes in existing routes.xml at runtime which adds/deletes to existing CamelContext.

Comment: @Developer If you want to operate on existing routes, you can do like:

1. You can get the context by exchange.getContext();
2. context has methods like removeRoute(theRouteId);